# Winforms - Show Datagrid selection in different window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a datagrid in a window.

If I double click, I need to show the selected row in text boxes in a new window.

When I double click a row, I can display the new form right now.

How can I know what row was double clicked in the new window..

I cannot find a way for my "form2", which is the new window, to have access to the datagrid which sent it...

How can the form2 know..

What "topics" should I read to understand this? Is this related to Data Binding?

Thanks

Comment: Create a public method on form2 and call it whenever the row is double clicked. That method should take an argument(s) the data you want to display

Comment: Hi...I am trying KiX suggestions and then will try to work your way...I think I understood your suggestion....Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define an event handler for CellDoubleClick or CellContentDoubleClick.
In the event handler function do this.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { 
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow) sender; //cast the sender object to DataGridViewRow
    Form2 newForm = new Form2(row);
    }
```

and in the Form2 constructor

```
    public class Form2 : Forms
    {
       private DataGridViewRow _row;

    public Form2(DataGridView row)
    {
        _row = row; // now you have a copy of the row in question
        txtFname.Text = _row.Cells[0].ToString(); 
        //row.Cells[0], row.Cells[1], row.Cells[n] will work here
    }
```

Comment: this depend on implementation. but i hope i have gave you an idea. Ideally you just want to pass the row in question. you don't need to know the whole datagridview.

Comment: a parameter on the constructor or a setter method will do for Form2.

Comment: Hi....How will I access the "row" in Form2.... if I try to assign txtfname = row[0].ToString(); it says row needs 2 arguments.....

Comment: see my comment. row is already available in that context. so intellisense will help you anyway. row.Cells is a collection of cells in that particular row. so row.Cells[0] will be the first column of the row.

Comment: I think i misunderstood you. I think the better approach is declaring a DataGridViewRow field inside Form2 class. I will edit it

Comment: txtFname.Text should be the one you use. txtFname is a TextBox object. so it should be txtFname.Text = row.Cells[0].ToString();

Comment: hi, I made these changes to your code......I put Form 2 newForm = new Form2(row);  instead of sender and.......I defined my Form2 as public Form2(DataGridViewRow row)..... I dont get any errors during compile but when I run the app, I get....Unable to cast object of type Forms.button to Type Forms.DataGridViewRow...... at the casting step....any ideas?

Comment: oh sorry about that. thats a typo row is the one you have to send :) Please give me the function signature of the event handler. I think you did not bind a handler for CellDoubleClick of the datagridview but from a button. THe meaning of the exception is that sender is of type Forms.Button(which is a button) but that should be a DataGridViewRow.